# Computer freeze when looping a large list of images in c# - Wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker, dispatcher

So i Have a very Simple software to call a multi Image list
and show them in a (**`Next`**) + (**`Previous`**) format like this :

[image]

and its work great for me but when i **Hold** on (NEXT) button **to pass all items fast** , after 10 or 20 item the whole window **freezes and Lag** , some recherche says to use background worker to prevent this so i tried to insert this :

```
var getImage = Directory.EnumerateFiles(DirName, Ext,
SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

***inside this :***

```
Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Background,
   new Action(() => /*### the Images output Here ###*/ ));
```

**but the same Issues still happening**

how to make it work correctly ?
and if there is any other way to do it i'll be happy to know it .

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke schedules a delegate to be executed on the UI thread. You don't want to execute any potentially long-running code on the UI thread. Why are you trying to do?

Comment: @mm8 i thought its gonna be better then `BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();` but i just dont have enough knowledge about Dispatcher and "BackgroundWorker " too , thats why i ask :) and if there is another way to avoid the lag when i call my images u can share with us :) ,  its a knowledge platform and we are here for that .

Comment: You should perform any long-running operation on a background thread but keep in mind that you can only access UI elements on the UI thread. Please refer to my answer for more information.

Comment: First of all, you should not be using `BackgroundWorker`. Everything it can do can be accomplished much more easily by using `Task.Run()`. Stephen Cleary has a nice series of articles on why you should use `Task.Run()` instead of `BackgroundWorker`. http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/05/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-intro.html

Comment: @NewellClark :: thanks both of you , i try this method , check my reply here maybe we can find a good way to do it :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42165688/call-directoryinfo-inside-dispatcher-invoke#comment71499572_42165962

Answer (score 2):

`Dispatcher.Invoke` schedules a delegate to be executed on the UI thread. You don't want to execute any potentially long-running code on the UI thread as this is what freezes your application.

If you want to call the `Directory.EnumerateFiles` on a background thread you could start a task:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> 
{
    //get the files on a background thread...
    return Directory.EnumerateFiles(DirName, Ext, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
}).ContinueWith(task => 
{
    //this code runs back on the UI thread
    IEnumerable<string> theFiles = task.Result; //...
}, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

Note that you cannot access any UI control on a background thread though so you should perform only the long-running work on the background thread and then you could use the `ContinueWith` method if you want to something with the results back on the UI thread, like for example setting the `ItemsSource` property of an ItemsControl or setting the `Visibility` property of a `ProgressBar` back to `Collapsed` or something.

Comment: thanks its give my Preview more Speed and the Lag was reduced , But the Window still freeze after holding on *"Next" button* long time :/ , i'm thinking that its maybe cause the images need to be saved on "Thumbs.db" in (%Temp%) after show them , so that Images doesn't need to be recalculated every time the Software view them ,, what you think ?.

Comment: Why the downvote? Anything you do on the UI thread will make your application less responsive as it cannot respond to events such as mouse movements and button clicks and execute your custom code simultaneously. So you need to either invoked your click event handler less frequently, off-load any work it is doing to a background thread or make it faster somehow. There are no shortcuts.